# Axial ratio of a square microstrip antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, radiation

I am currently designing by CP microstrip antenna using CST. The picture is shown below. However, when I view the axial ratio plot, also shown below it is way above 3dB at 90 degrees. the patch is 31,95 by 31.95mm.  The resonate frequency output is correct which is 915MHz. I have tried varying multiple variables such as the length of the patch, length of the main feed, the distance between the branched feed line and the patch (quater-wavelength feed line). But the axial ratio does not change much. How can I alter the axial ratio to be below 3dB but keep the resonate frequency at 915MHz?

[image]
[image]